# Move Ellipse and Oval Shapes in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, ellipse

I am trying to draw a robot using swing. The robot object is comprised of several ellipses and ovals. I need to create a method to move the robot around the JFrame depending on a user's input. I started out using rectangles for the robot, so I could just use the translate method to move it. But that doesn't exist for ellipses. How can I write a new method to move the shapes? Here is what I have so far:

```
public class SwingBot 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setTitle("SwingBot");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Robot r = new Robot();

    frame.add(r);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean repeat = true;
    System.out.println();
    while (repeat)
    {
        String str = in.next();
        String direc = str.toLowerCase();
        if (direc.equals("right"))
        {
            r.moveBot(10,0);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("left"))
        {
            r.moveBot(-10,0);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("up"))
        {
            r.moveBot(0,-10);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("down"))
        {
            r.moveBot(0,10);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("exit"))
        {
            repeat = false;
        }
    }

}


public static class Robot extends JComponent
{
    private Ellipse2D e = new Ellipse2D.Double(20,20,100,50);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillOval(45,60,50,50);
        g2.fill(e);

        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillOval(40,40,20,20);
        g2.fillOval(80,40,20,20);


    }

    public void moveBot(int x, int y)
    {

        repaint();
    }

}
```

}

The moveBot method at the bottom is empty because it originally had the translate method called on some rectangle objects, but I changed those to ellipses and ovals. Now I don't know how to move these without the translate method.

Comment: Um... just change the x and y of the robot and use those variables inside the paintComponent() method. The moveBot() method would set the x with `this.x = this.x + x;`

Comment: use variables for your hard code numbers to represent relative position, then change the variables to where you want to move it.

Comment: It's not a good idea to try to combine a Swing GUI with a Scanner that runs on the console, and you're much better of sticking with either all one or all the other -- here a Swing GUI with Key Bindings. Also, you will want to avoid use of `while (true)` loops in Swing GUI's. It sort of works here because you're calling it on the main thread, but if you changed your program in a little bit, it will run in the Swing thread and completely shut-down your program. Better to use a Swing Timer for your game/animation loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `x` and `y` of the robot inside the `moveBot()` method and use those variables inside the `paintComponent()` method

For example: (using your code)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SwingBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setTitle("SwingBot");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Robot r = new Robot();

        frame.add(r);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean repeat = true;
        System.out.println();
        while (repeat) {
            String str = in.next();
            String direc = str.toLowerCase();
            if (direc.equals("right")) {
                r.moveBot(10, 0);
            } else if (direc.equals("left")) {
                r.moveBot(-10, 0);
            } else if (direc.equals("up")) {
                r.moveBot(0, -10);
            } else if (direc.equals("down")) {
                r.moveBot(0, 10);
            } else if (direc.equals("exit")) {
                repeat = false;
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Robot extends JComponent {
        int x = 45;
        int y = 60;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Ellipse2D e = new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 25, y - 40, 100, 50);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
            g2.fill(e);

            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.fillOval(x - 5, y - 20, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(x + 35, y - 20, 20, 20);

        }

        public void moveBot(int x, int y) {

            setX(getX() + x);
            setY(getY() + y);
            repaint();
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

    }

}
```